# PHP autoload looking in current php file

Tags: php, codeigniter

In file: `deckclass.php`  , with DOCROOT set to `/var/www/Proj/application/controllers`

**getting error:** Fatal error: Class 'Cardclass' not found in `/var/www/Proj/application/controllers/deckclass.php` on line 38

Why is it searching current php file and not DOCROOT folder?

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
  //class directories
  $filename = DOCROOT .strtolower($class_name) . ".php";
  if ( file_exists($filename) )
  {
    require_once ($filename);
  }
  else {
    throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.");
  }
}

$card = new Cardclass();
```

Comment: Do you have any php file named as Cardclass in your controller folder?

Comment: yes it's called cardclass.php

Comment: Then Just do `echo $filename;`  and check the output path

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was not a solution, I suppose for some reason the autoload method is not registered, otherwise you would be able to print the filename, unfortunately I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));` and `define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

> #### Tip
>
> **spl_autoload_register()** provides a more flexible alternative for
>   autoloading classes. For this reason, using **__autoload()** is
>   discouraged and may be **deprecated or removed** in the future.

So do code should look like this:

```
     <?php
        define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__)); //This is full path
        spl_autoload_register('Autoloader'); //You can use annonymous function here
        function Autoloader($class_name){
          $filename = ROOT.DS.strtolower($class_name).".php";
          var_dump($filename);
          if(file_exists($filename)){
            require_once ($filename);
          }else{
            throw new Exception("Unable to load ".$class_name."in".$filename);
          }
        }

        $card = new Cardclass();
```

With __autoload:

```
<?php
        define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__)); //This is full path
        function __autoload($class_name){
          $filename = ROOT.DS.strtolower($class_name).".php";
          var_dump($filename);
          if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {

             if(file_exists($filename)){
               require_once ($filename);
            }else{
               throw new Exception("Unable to load ".$class_name."in".$filename);
            }
          }
        }

        $card = new Cardclass();
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Function 'Autoloader' not found` on `spl_autoload_register('Autoloader');`

Comment: `Unable to load the requested file: helpers/spl_autoload_helper.php` i'm using PHP 5.3 too.

Comment: @Undermine2k What is result of ´echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();´

Comment: it says current version is 5.3.10-1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59065/discussion-between-veeenex-and-undermine2k).